# Existence of Beta Function?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider $$\beta(x,y) = \int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}\,dt$$

For which $x,y \in \mathbb R$ does this function exist?

The problem I'm having with this is that there seems to be too many cases to test, as opposed to say the gamma function, where there's only one variable to consider. Now when $x \geq 1$ and $y \geq 1$ the integrand reduces to a polynomial which is continuous on $[0,1]$, so clearly the beta function exists when both $x$ and $y$ are greater than or equal to $1$. But how would I consider the cases where only one of $x$ and $y$ are greater than or equal to $1$, or when both are less than $1$?

Comment: Why are you looking at $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$? The natural domain is the complex numbers.

Comment: Well as the tag suggests, this is a real analysis question because that's what I'm studying. I'm not concerned with complex numbers.

Comment: So you do not know any complex analysis?

Comment: The behaviour of the function for negative x,y is at first sight rather complicated. You need to start by proving the relationship with the gamma function. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function you start by looking at $\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)$.

Comment: Well since $\Gamma(x)$ exists for $x<0$, I don't see how the relation $\beta(x,y) = \frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$ can be used to prove that $\beta(x,y)$ requires $x>0$ and $y>0$ to exist. In fact, that just makes things more confusing. If $\Gamma(x)$ exists for $x<0$ (where $x$ is not a negative integer), then $\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)$ and $\Gamma(x+y)$ both exist for negative values of $x$ and $y$, so why is it that the Beta function doesn't exist for these values?

Answer (score 2):

**Outline:** The potential problems are at $0$ and $1$, so we consider the integrals from $0$ to $1/2$ and from $1/2$ to $1$ separately.

It turns out that the integral from $0$ to $1/2$ exists if and only if $x\gt 0$. By symmetry, the integral from $1/2$ to $1$ exists iff $y\gt 0$.

For a proof, use Comparison, and the probably familiar fact that $\int_0^{1/2} \frac{1}{x^p}\,dx$ converges if and only if $p\lt 1$.

Note that for any $y$, there exist $c$ and $d$ such that $0\lt c\lt (1-t)^{y-1}\lt d$  in the interval $[0,1/2]$. So 
$$\int_0^{1/2} t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}\,dt\quad\text{converges iff}\quad\int_0^{1/2}t^{x-1}\,dt\quad\text{converges}.$$

Comment: It seems there is a user who doesn't like you, I just can't believe it there is a such person like that. +1 anyway

Comment: It happens a fair bit, mainly in spurts. It is unfortunate, for a couple of reasons. A downvote may make someone searching the site doubt the correctness of the answer. Also, when a question/answer combination has downvotes, in the long run the question may get deleted. I am not happy when an answer that might be useful to others disappears!

Comment: Added: Some people when they see an unreasonable downvote want to compensate by **upvoting** other answers by the same person. That is **not** a good idea.

Comment: I just wanna be nice, though.